# Why is Matt Ryan nicknamed "Matty Ice"?

Tags: american-football, trivia, nfl

Where did Atlanta Falcons' quarterback Matt Ryan get his nickname?

Answer (score 5):

[According to NBC Sports analyst Ross Tucker](https://twitter.com/rosstuckernfl/status/655916246244966400?lang=en):

> Matt Ryan's nickname "Matty Ice" not from clutch play but affinity for Natural Ice in high school.

Basically, he is named after a beer.

Comment: I saw the same tweet, but it looks like there are [conflicting stories](http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/15361) as to the actual origin of the nickname.

Comment: @ᴍᴀsᴛᴇʀᴍɪɴᴅ_ᴇᴅ Yeah, hard to tell which one can be considered viable. I ultimately chose the tweet because it was from seven years sooner, but really either could be true and a newer source doesn't necessarily dictate greater credibility.

Comment: You're saying kids drink beer in high school??? The shock!!

Comment: Also, I've seen conflicting reports on high school vs. college.  (Apparently Natty Ice is a big beer at Boston College, so that would make sense.)  I definitely think the Natural/Natty Ice connection is relevant, even if it also came from the high school baseball context.

Answer (score 2):

According to his high school ([William Penn Charter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Penn_Charter_School)) baseball coach, Richard Mellor:

> "Matt started his first varsity baseball game as a freshman, at third
>   base against Malvern Prep. We were playing against his older brother,
>   Motts. Matt had two hits, no errors, and we won. That's how he got the
>   nickname Matty Ice."

Sources: [(1)](http://www.espn.com/espnmag/story?id=3385125) [(2)](http://www.espn.com/espnmag/story?id=3682091)

Comment: Pretty weird to get the "ice" from having two hits and no errors in a regular game...  I've done that in my softball league numerous times and never got a nickname for it...

Comment: I have a feeling this is one of those "stories high school kids tell adults so they don't admit to breaking the law."